# Is it possible to filter exim_mainlog for emails that had attachments?

Tags: centos, email, logging, exim

Is it possible to filter (grep) exim_mainlog for emails that had attachments? I'm looking through a really long log for an email of which I don't have any information about other than the sender and that it had an attachment. Sender alone returned hundreds (POOMA) of entries. So I'd like to narrow it down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "S=" part of the log entry is the size of the message.  Assuming the sender attached something more substantial than what was usually sent, you could try looking for a large email that way.